# How to print user name after login?

Tags: php, html, session

I want after somone is logging in to display the user name on another page page , also is this a good way for login ?

```html
<?php

session_start();

$database =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

if (isset($_POST['login_bn'])) {
 
 $usrname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['usrname']);
 $pas = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['pas']);
 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE usrname='$usrname' AND pas='$pas'";
 $result = mysqli_query($database, $sql);
 
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
  
  header("location: home.php");
 
 } 
 
?>
```

And i want to display the username here on the nav bar somwhere

```html
<?php

session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

  <button onclick="'">Log Out </button>

<ul>
<!-- Here somehwere -->

<li><a href="main.html"> Home</a></li>


</ul>
```

sorry for newbie  Question

Comment: PHP is stateless, so you need to store the users details in a `_SESSION`. Once you have done this, you will be able to access it from any page (as long as you do `session_start();` at the top.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: get a `session` value to next page and print the name e.g for ` <?php echo $_SESSION['uname'];?>` but you need to start session using `session_start();`

Comment: You are storing password as plain text PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: I will look intro SQL injection and password_hash().

Comment: And thank you all for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, should read this **[Session in php](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)**

set session in login page `$_SESSION["usrname"] = $usrname;` and get value in 
home.php

```
<?php    
    session_start();    
    $database =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");
    if (isset($_POST['login_bn'])) {    
        $usrname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['usrname']);
        $pas = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['pas']);   
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE usrname='$usrname' AND pas='$pas'";
        $result = mysqli_query($database, $sql);    
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $_SESSION["usrname"] = $usrname;
            header("location: home.php");   
        }   
    ?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="'">Log Out </button>
<ul>
<!-- Here somehwere -->
<?php  echo $_SESSION["usrname"]; ?>
<li><a href="main.html"> Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

After selecting data from mysql

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $result['usrname'];
    header("location: home.php");

}
```

In home.php file just echo the username session wherever you want

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['uname'];?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php

   session_start();

   $database =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

   if (isset($_POST['login_bn'])) {

    $usrname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['usrname']);
    $pas = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['pas']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE usrname='$usrname' AND pas='$pas'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

        $_SESSION['userName']=/*user name here*/
        header("location: home.php");

    }   
  ?>
```

than just call `$_SESSION['userName']` anywhere in your application to get the name of logged in user

Answer (score 1):

try this code :-

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login_bn'])) {

$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE usrname='".$usrname."' AND pas='".$pas."'");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
if(!empty($row))
{
$_SESSION["user_name"]=$row["first_name"]." ".$row["last_name"];//and access it anywhere after session_start(); as echo $_SESSION["user_name"]
header("location: home.php");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**PHP Sessions**](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.session.php) for this.

Change you first code snippet to

```
<?php

session_start();

$database =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

if (isset($_POST['login_bn'])) {

    $usrname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['usrname']);
    $pas = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['pas']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE usrname='$usrname' AND pas='$pas'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['usrname']=$usrname
        header("location: home.php");

    } 

?>
```

Then you can access it from any page (as long as you do `session_start();`) by using `$_SESSION['usrname']`

For example if you want to print out out the username, then you just have to call

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['usrname']; ?>
```